# How can I use WSGI for my Flask app? My app uses thread

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, gunicorn, wsgi

I have a python program. It produces new thread which is API server. It works on test environment. However I want to use WSGI (e.g. gunicorn) on production environment. How can I do it without major change?

There are many reasons why I want to use WSGI but one big reason is that I want to set up timeout in order to kill open connections for very slow requests. I am facing a performance issue. The very slow request affects another requests eventually.

*files

```
├── server.py
└── api.py
```

*server.py

```
import time
import api

api_server = api.APIServer()
api_server.daemon = True
api_server.start()

while True:
  time.sleep(1)
```

*api.py

```
import threading
from flask import Flask

class APIServer(threading.Thread):

  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
      return 'hello'

    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, threaded=True)
```

---

Update 1

The real code is here. I picked up some from this code.

https://github.com/CounterpartyXCP/counterparty-lib/blob/master/counterpartylib/server.py#L403

vidstige's way is absolutely right. But I don't want to change a lot if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part for you is to make sure you run your other thread smoothly. I suggest doing it in two steps

1. Change the threads around so that the other stuff is started in a background thread.
2. Then switch to gunicorn, you can start the background thread using `post_worker_init` server hook.

Your thread is not really needed here. You can just immediately switch to `gunicorn`. Just install `pip install gunicorn` and move out the app to e.g. `server.py`. This is very important.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return 'hello'
```

Now you can run it without threads like so `FLASK_APP=server.py flask run`. Once you have it at this point you can switch to a production WSGI such as gunicorn. Just launch it like this instead.

```
gunicorn server:app
```

Once you can run using gunicorn, you can [configure](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html) it to use multiple threads, and even processes. If your work is IO-bound I recommend using `gevent` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. As I added "Update 1", I don't want to divide the files since the real code is a little bit big and tested. But I'm thinking dividing it and test again since your suggestion is much better.

Comment: ah, yes, that's makes a lot of difference. In the actual code you actually need the thread. Instead of changing as little as possible, I recommend making the change in small steps. For example, first reversing things so that the other stuff runs in a thread and the web app is "naked" in a file so that you can run it with gunicorn. Now you can start the other thread using a `post_worker_init ` hook